# Numerical Analysis - Upper bound for $|R|$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am asked to find an upper bound for $|R|$ valid for all $x\in[-1,1]$ that is independent of $x$ and $\xi$.

Given that,

$$R(x)=\frac{|x|^6}{6!}e^\xi$$

for $x\in[-1,1]$ where $\xi$ is between $x$ and $0$. I began with stating that

$$|R_n(x)|=\frac{|x^{n+1}e^{c_x}|}{(n+1)!},$$
$$=\frac{|x|^{n+1}e^{c_x}}{(n+1)!},$$
because $e^z > 0$ for all $z$ and 
$$|R_n(x)|\leq\frac{e^{c_x}}{(n+1)!},$$
because $|x|\leq 1$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$

Does this satisfy the question or will I need more?

Comment: Doesn't the trivial upper bound $\dfrac e{6!}$ work for you?

Comment: I think so, I arrived at $|R|=\frac{e}{6!}$, however. And this is the correct approach, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both $x,\xi \in [-1,1]$, we have $|x|\le 1$ and $|\xi|\le 1$ and so
$$
|R(x)|= \left|\frac{|x|^6}{6!}e^\xi\right| \le \frac{1}{6!} e^1=\frac{e}{6!}
$$